# Sed - How do I remove the extra characters that show up after running the command?

Tags: sed

First off, I never used sed before so this might seem like a stupid question. So I think ran the command correctly but my script only replaces the first letter with BANNED and not the rest of it. I am supposed to use sed to remove any word that begins with 'S' and replace it with the word BANNED.

This is how I made my script

```
 sed -e 's/ S/ BANNED/g' -e 's/ s/ BANNED/g' input.txt
```

The final product is supposed to look like this:

```
The BANNED (BANNED editor) utility is a batch (noninteractive) editor. It takes its input from files you BANNED on the command line or from BANNED input. Unless you redirect the output from BANNED, it goes to BANNED output. BANNED it goes.
```

But mine looks like this:

```
The BANNEDED (stream editor) utility is a batch (noninteractive) editor. It takes its input from files you BANNEDpecify on the command line or from BANNEDtandard input. Unless you redirect the output from BANNEDed, it goes to BANNEDtandard output. BANNEDo it goes.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't say to replace "any word that begins with s", it replaces "s".

Comment: Add content of input.txt to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you search for an `s` or `S` preceded by a space, and replace that with `BANNED`. This is why your `sed` only replaces the first character of the "word".

In addition, your regex isn't really looking for "words". Its rather restrictive since it assumes "words" starting with an `s` or `S` will always be preceded by a space (which is not the case in general).

**Try something like this instead:**

```
sed -E 's/(\b)[sS]\w*(\b)/\1BANNED\2/g'
```

**Explanation:**

- `[sS]\w*` is a "word" starting with `s` or `S`, containing zero or more characters
- `\b` is a "word boundary", such as a space, period, end of line, etc
- The `-E` option is used for extended regex syntax; used here for the use of square brackets to match `s` or `S`
- Notice the use of parentheses around the `\b`s -- this captures the word boundary. We then use the "backreferences" `\1` and `\2` to re-insert the word boundary character back in (whatever it may be).

**Limitation:**

The use of `\w` here could be a fair approximation of what a "word" looks like (usually defined to mean a letter, digit or underscore). If it doesn't suit your needs, then you can replace it with something else, e.g. `[a-zA-Z'-]` could be more suitable for many common English words.